# How to make a segue append a a tableview in another Vc in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, label, segue

Still learning and not very bright.
In 2 VCs: the first one has some labels that perform a segue to a tableview in a second VC.
Although the code says append, it works only once. 
There is an unwind from the second VC to the first, but when I push the button to append and "feed" the tableview, it does not append, it replace the first segue.
I believe this is because the segue, since it will always shows a brand new VC and not append the tableview, this way I lose the first "insert". Or, there is an issue with the append code.
Any help or sample how to append a tableview in another VC would be very helpful. I looked for a lot but it seems there is always a segue FROM tableview not TO a tableview.
I thank in advance any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new file ApplicationData.swift and write down following code:

```
import Foundation

class ApplicationData {
    static var shared = ApplicationData()

    var cities = ["Austin", "Barcelona", "Canberra", "Darwin", "Florida", "Moscow"]

    private init() {
        print("Shared instance succuessfully instantiated")
    }
}
```

in any of your view controller you should add variable:

```
var applicationData = ApplicationData.shared
```

No matter which controller changes cities property of the variable it will affect one and only instance shared within your application.

Comment: Hello Andrey, thanks for your comment. Apologies for my poor understanding but what you are saying is that a should create a singleton and declare in it the segue and the variables and labels? Is that possible? Connecting the labels and tableviews of different VCs?

Comment: Hey, Andrey, thanks for your help. I did as you said and now I can't change the value of the var inside the class. If you could, please see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141320/change-value-of-a-var-inside-a-class-swift. Would you give another light? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rafa, try changing public static let shared = listas.init() to static var shared = listas.init()